# Modelling (deterministic) trend with nnetar

Tags: r, forecasting, trend

how do you handle trends with nnetar? What would be the best way to forecast for this example:

```
 library(timeDate)
 library(forecast)
 library(lattice)
 library(ggplot2)
 library(caret)

 set.seed(1234)

 T <- seq(0,100,length=100)
 Y <- 10 + 2*T + rnorm(100)

 fit <- nnetar(Y)

 plot(forecast(fit,h=30))
 points(1:length(Y),fitted(fit),type="l",col='red')
```

Thx&kind regards

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have two options.

1. You can tell `nnetar` to use more orders (if you print `fit` you'll see it only used one lag in your example).

   ```
   fit <- nnetar(Y, p=5)
   plot(forecast(fit,h=30))
   ```
2. You can add the trend directly to the model as an external regressor with the `xreg` argument. Note that you also need to provide that argument for the forecast (the values I gave are not exactly right for your example, but work well enough for illustrative purposes).

   ```
   fit <- nnetar(Y, xreg=T)
   plot(forecast(fit,xreg=101:130, h=30))
   ```

For your example problem, either works. Although more generally, if you know what the trend is, the second option is probably best.

By the way, keep in mind that R [uses capital "T" as shorthand for `TRUE`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/logical.html) (and similarly "F" for `FALSE`), so overriding this can cause some confusion or induce bugs. For example, it made me do a double take after writing `xreg=T`.